# convert bytes to stings and eliminate hex in twitter data

Tags: python, twitter, encoding, utf

I need to remove hex from strings that have been converted from bytes in Python3.

I can convert from byte to string, but then I can't find my way around encoding the hex or removing them automatically. I tried to encode as ASCII but it doesn't work.

My text data a value under the key "tweet_text" in a list of dictionaries.
Here is my code:

```
    for d in sheet_data:
        just_text = d['tweet_text']
        print('This is "just_text" type: ', type(just_text))
        just_text_strings = str(just_text)
        print('This is "just_text_strings" type: ', type(just_text_strings))
        just_text_clean = just_text_strings.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')
```

Here is my output:

```
This is "just_text" type:  <class 'bytes'>
This is "just_text_strings" type:  <class 'str'>
b'b"[/Very seldom~ will someone enter your life] and you won\'t have to question\\xc3\\xa2\\xe2\\x82\\xac\\xc2\\xa6 "'
```

I appreciate any advice or ideas to fix this issue.... this is Twitter data, in case that helps

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not string encoding, but rather the terminal encoding type. I ran this command in Windows terminal:

```
chcp 65001
```

Just typed that in the terminal. Got this output:

```
Active code page: 65001
```

and then the characters were showing fine.

I couldn't yet remove the characters, as I want to do, but at least the 'b' before strings and hex have dissappeared.